# Using "Select INTO" for million of records

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I'm using the `SELECT INTO` statement to create my SQL statement result.

```
SELECT fields
    INTO [newtable]
    FROM table1, table2, table3, table4
    [where clause to filter records from four tables]
```

I would like to know how this statement would impact the performance if there million of records to insert into new table. Will there be `OutOfMemory` error in this case?

My environment is SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Why would there be a memory issue?  You may have a log table issue but that would depend on what logging mode you are using and how much space each existing data row uses.

Comment: It's a server based database - it manages memory for you.

Comment: If you find yourself creating millions of rows in some kind of holding/temporary table, then generally you shouldn't worry about how it performs, you should *stop* doing that. Is it possible that you've broken what should be a single logical query down into a series of separate steps? If so, try not to do that. Write a *single* query that specifies the original inputs and the overall result and let the *server* determine which intermediate results should/should not be spilled into temporary storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will there be OutOfMemory error in this case?

1. SQL Server is going to guess how many records you are inserting. It will then ask the OS for that much memory, hopefully avoiding an out of memory situation.
2. If SQL Server isn't given enough memory, or if it asks for too little, it will temporarily store the excess data in TempDB. As the name suggests, TempDB is a temporary database that lives on disk. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190768.aspx
3. To ensure good performance, put as much RAM as possible on your database server.
4. To ensure good performance, put your TempDB on its own hard drive. And make sure you buy an SSD hard drive, not a cheap spinner.
5. If you look at the execution plan in SQL Server Management Studio, you can see details such as how much memory the query used. http://www.developer.com/db/understanding-a-sql-server-query-execution-plan.html
6. If the memory SQL Server used is very different than the memory it asked for, your statistics are probably out of date. (Search for "SQL Server Statistics" for more info.)

Comment: it's splendid explanation

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't store the data in memory while it is transferring the data so there shouldn't be memory issues. 
Logging and IO performance would take a hit as you are creating millions of rows. Also performance would downgrade if your joins are complex in your select statement (if the select alone takes ages then the insert will be even longer)

Comment: my joins are simple. so i would stick with this 'select into' statement thanks

Answer (score 0):

SELECT INTO is typically used to generate temp tables or to copy another table (data and/or structure).

SELECT INTO is usually much **better performance** wise since it is `minimally logged`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `temp table` with the necessary fields from the following tables
ex:

```
create table #temp_data
(
empid int,
emp_name varchar(50),
strt_date datetime,
emp_addrss varchar(50),
emp_sal numeric
)
```

Next insert the date from the four tables to the following columns with necessary conditions required.

```
insert #temp_data values
(
001,'raj','2013-04-03','hyderabad',25000
)
Update 
update #temp_data
(
empid,emp_name,strt_date,emp_address,emp_sal
)
```

Now write the query as per ur requirements with `where clause` and all

```
select 
empid,emp_name,strt_date,emp_addrss,emp_sal
from #temp_data
where empid = 001
```

### Sol:

```
empid   emp_name      strt_date         emp_addrss  emp_sal
1        raj    2013-04-03 00:00:00.000 hyderabad   25000
```